# I am trying to install django-heroku on my Mac but am getting the below error

Tags: psycopg2, pg-config

> Error:
> pg_config executable not found.

```
pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I am a beginner so my knowledge is pretty loose on all factors above. A simplified step-by-step explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pip install psycopg2-binary` then install django-heroku again.

The error is just simply saying that your computer can't find psycopg2-binary package

Comment: I followed the above, installed psycopg2-binary then tried installing django-heroku again but was given the same error. :/